# Can/How do I get data from an external JS object into a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and want to start using it with my CMS. Due to certain limitations, I must build the component/app locally and copy the compiled JS up onto my CMS. This seems to work.

Now, I want to populate the props of my components with data from the CMS. I thought a good way would be to create a JS object on the CMS and get the React app to pick that up.

The thing is I don't know how to do that locally. I cannot access the data object with an absolute path as (for now) it's just some in-line JS. eg:

```
<script>
    const componentObj = {
        title: "Hello! I'm Data from obj";
    };
</script>
```

In my (very simple) React app I've tried ternary operators, `try catch` and `if (typeof componentObj !== 'undefined') {` but none work. They fail to build as `componentObj` is not defined locally.

```
function App() {

  const greeting = componentObj.title ? componentObj.title : 'Data not from component object';

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Welcome text={greeting}/>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

const Welcome = (props) => {
  return <h1>{props.text}</h1>; 
};
```

Would anyone know how to approach this or what I have done wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: `locally` - you mean your CMS is somewhere on internet and React must download JS code from it to use in local environment (your PC)

Comment: @Justinas No. I can set the default values locally, as with the ternary above. I just want to create something that says "if this object is availble use its data, else use the data hardcoded into the component." When the component is built and deployed to the CMS I want it to pick up the object on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was actually having was with ESLint. It would not let React compile due to it seeing undefined variables.

I found I could get ESLint to ignore certain lines of code by adding

`// eslint-disable-line`

to the end of the line, eg:

```
  const greeting = componentObj.title ? componentObj.title : 'Data not from component object'; // eslint-disable-line
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to store it in separate JS file? If so, you need to import it on top of the file in which you use that list of objects.

For example, in ComponentList.js your data looks like this:

```
export const ComponentList= [
    { title: "about1" },
    { title: "about2" },
    ...
];
```

And in other component you need to import it at the top to use it:

```
import { ComponentList } from "../Data/ComponentList"; // Import from Data folder

const SomeComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      // use that list 
      {ComponentList.length === 0 ? (
        <p>ComponentList is empty</p>
      ) : (
        ComponentList.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            {item.title}
          </div>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SomeComponent;
```

You can do the same thing you did with ternary operator to check if it's empty or not and conditionally display a text message.

Comment: Thanks, but that would still compile the object as part of the build, wouldn't it? Eg I couldn't get dynamic values from another object in the CMS?